# Does latex_header_extra work in org 9?

Tags: org-mode, preview-latex

In the [org-mode manual](http://orgmode.org/manual/Header-and-sectioning.html) says

> Unlike LATEX_HEADER, contents from LATEX_HEADER_EXTRA keywords will not be loaded when previewing LaTeX snippets

---

If I start Emacs using `emacs -q`, it loads `org version 8.2.10` from the shared libraries and the following fragment works fine.

```
#+LATEX_HEADER_EXTRA: \newcommand{\test}{testing}
$\test$
```

The newcommand has no effect on the preview and when I use `org-preview-latex-fragment` I simply get a blank image. However, in `org version 9.0.9`, starting `emacs` with an empty config file and using `org-toggle-latex-fragment`, this fragment creates an image with the text "testing". It is using the command inside the preview (!).

Is it possible to use `LATEX_HEADER_EXTRA` on `9.0.9`? I have tried byte-recompiling `org` and `org-plus`, and my Emacs is being loaded without any initial configuration but I have not been able to use it.

Comment: In 8.3, [changes](http://orgmode.org/Changes_old.html) to `org-toggle-latex-fragment` were introduced, I am starting to think that this is a bug (?)

Comment: Emacs  : GNU Emacs 26.0.50 (build 1, x86_64-pc-linux-gnu, GTK+ Version 3.22.12)
 of 2017-04-28

Package: Org mode version 9.0.9 (9.0.9-elpaplus @ /home/mario/.emacs.d/elpa/org-plus-contrib-20170622/)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The bug has been fixed by Nicolas Goaziou in [this commit](http://orgmode.org/cgit.cgi/org-mode.git/commit/?id=e903288e5080775cbd4d87c69deeba3268cda5c1).